# Make changes to main form with ahah callback in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, drupal-fapi

I have a form like poll form.When there is no data in db I want to show only add button and when user clicks "more" I want to show him/her a submit button.
I used the following code but it seems doesn't works.

```
if ($form['count']['#value'] > 0) {
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Submit')
  );
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values will be in $form_state['values'] so try:

```
if($form_state['values']['count'] > 0){....
```

I would expect that at this point the $form['count']['#value'] is not set.